# Кешерование данных с сайта

Tags: html, http

Как управлять кешированием? С одной стороны мне надо, что б информация не кешировалась, иначе пользователи не увидят новых сообщений, для этого я делаю:

1) в заголовки ответа с сервера выдаю:

> Цитата

```
Cache-Control: no-transform
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

2) в HTML коде указываю:

> Цитата

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Но вот оказывается, что не все надо не кешировать, кое что желательно не загружать повторно. Из самого крупного это Ява скрипты и стили.

Answer (score 1):

Ява скрипты и стили и так кэшируются браузером самостоятельно.
В самом простом варианте создайте папочку cached_pages - в ней храните ваши закешированные страницы. Как только обновляете страницу сами, сразу после обновление удаляете её кешированный файл из папки cached_pages. Как только пользователь заходит на страницу проверяйте есть ли она в папке cached_pages, если да то грузите ёе оттуда, если нет, загружайте из базы данных (далее, после загрузки можете её сразу же поместить в cached_pages и у всех последующих она будет из кэща браться). Это самый тривиальный пример.

Comment: смотрел по https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/ оно мне выдало такой результат - Используйте кэш браузера: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css и style.css (не указан срок истечения действия). вот и вожусь. Ваш вариант очень тяжел в реализации, по большому счету это надо весь движок переписывать...
более простого варианта нет?

Comment: А стили и скрипты вы на лету генерите ? или они просто лежат у вас на диске ?

Comment: скорее всего генерит :) ахахахахахахаха... блин поражаюсь!

Comment: Я решал подобную задачу создание контроллера для публичных файлов который, в зависимости от настроек говорил браузеру кешировать или нет тот или иной файл, довольно удобно было.

@yarnik - если и не нужно этого делать сейчас, рано или поздно это сделать прийдется ;D

Comment: chernomyrdin, нет конечно.  
Гоблин не угадал.  
AlexWindHope, я что то не понял о чем вы, можно подробнее?

Comment: @yarnik по моему вы придумали сами себе проблему. Кэширование необходимо для того чтобы снизить нагрузку, например, на базу данных, т.е. обойти узкие места. Почитайте про кэширование в nginx: http://dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/56.html

Answer (score -1):

Я писал систему кэширования на CMS, сталкивался с подобной проблемой, решал проблему появления новых постов и комментариев очень просто, при добавлении нового поста или комментария очищал кеш, и система сразу снова кэшировала страницу.

Comment: какая схема реализации?